# Approximation of $\arctan(x)$ with $\pi/2 + a/x + b/x^3$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

> I have to find numbers $a, b \in \mathbf{R}$ that function
>   $f(x) = \pi/2 + a/x + b/x^3$ is a very good approximation to the function $g(x) = \arctan(x)$ for big $x$ in terms of that the error goes towards $0$ faster than $1/x^4$, where $x$ goes towards $\infty$.

So I calculate the derivative of functions $f$ and $g$ and equate them. When I all calculate then I got 
$(a +1) x^4 + (a + b) x^2 + b = 0$

Is this the right path for this exercise or not?

Comment: You may find Taylor expansions to be useful.

Comment: If you mean the arctangent function by the notation $arctg,$ please be aware that the $\LaTeX$ command `\arctan` is the more usual notation. Also, `\infty` gives you $\infty.$

Comment: Which one of the Taylor exapnsions I use?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the fact that for $x > 0$, we have $\arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{1}{x})$.  Then, apply the Taylor series
$$\arctan t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} t^{2n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use

$$\arctan x=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$ $$ = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\int_x^\infty\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{1}{1+1/t^2}\, dt.$$

To deal with the last integral, recall that $\dfrac{1}{1+u} = 1-u+u^2 - \cdots$ for $|u|<1.$